# Log File as a List?

Tags: c, list, logging

For a project I have to complete a log template provided by the text book.

The code provided is as follows:

```
#include <time.h>
typedef struct data_struct {
  time_t time;
  char *string;
} data_t;

int addmsg(data_t data);
void clearlog(void);
char *getlog(void);
int savelog(char *filename);

//
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "log.h"

typedef struct list_struct {
  data_t item;
  struct list_struct *next;
} log_t;

static log_t *headptr = NULL;
static log_t *tailptr = NULL;

int addmsg(data_t data) {
  return 0;
}

void clearlog(void) {
}

char *getlog(void) {
  return NULL;
}

int savelog(char *filename) {
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I think I was able to do `addmsg` and `clearlog`, but I'm coming up short for `getlog` and `savelog`.

Instructions for these two functions are:

> The `getlog` function allocates enough space for a string containing the entire log, copies the log into this string, and returns a pointer to the string. It is the responsibility of the calling program to free this memory when necessary. A successful `getlog` call returns a pointer to the log string. An unsuccessful `getlog` call returns `NULL`.
>
> The `savelog` function saves the logged messages to a disk file. If successful, `savelog` return 0, otherwise return -1.
>
> These functions also set `errno` on failure.

So far, all I have is trying to determine the size of the log, with

```
int logsize = sizeof(log_t) + 1;
```

I don't really know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

For `addmsg`, we were given a program that had similar functionality to work with, and when adapted for this program I ended up with

```
int addmsg(data_t data) {
  log_t *newnode;
  int nodesize;
  nodesize = siezeof(log_t) + strlen(data.string) + 1;
  if ((newnode = (log_t *)(malloc(nodesize))) == NULL //can't add
    return -1; //add failed
  newnode->item.time = date.time;
  newnode->item.string = (char *)newnode + sizeof(log_t);
  strcpy(newnode->item.string, data.string);
  newnode->next = NULL;
  if (headptr == NULL)
    headptr = newnode;
  else
    tailptr->next = newnode;
  tailptr = newnode;
  return 0;
}
```

If it were as simple as iterating through a file, I wouldn't have an issue. I'm just not used to handling nodes and pointers. I don't know how to iterate through these (as they aren't automatically put into a file when the message is added) to find the string length and allocate the proper memory for `getlog`.

For `clearlog`:

```
void clearlog(void) {
  static log_t *current = *headptr;
  static log_t *next;
  while (current != NULL) {
    next = current->next;
    free(current);
    current = next;
  }
  *headptr = NULL;
}
```

This iterates through the messages, but I don't know how to implement this to copy the string in each node for `getlog`.

Comment: Post what you have done for `addmsg` and `clearlog,` and detail issues with the other 2.

Comment: Did as asked. I know as soon as I know how to do getlog I can do savelog.

Comment: 1) `siezeof` --> `sizeof`  2)  `if ((newnode = (log_t *) (malloc(nodesize))) == NULL` --> `if ((newnode = (log_t *) (malloc(nodesize))) == NULL) {`  3) `date.time;` --> `data.time` `log_t *current = *headptr;` and `*headptr = NULL;` are wrong - unclear what you want.  5) Suggest compiling with all warning enabled and fix code until it has no warnings/errors and then post that.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the correct place to ask a question of this nature. You are basically asking us to do your homework.

Your homework questions can be broken down into two main parts though

- how to write to a file
- how to get the log as a string from the data structure, allocating memory as needed

Writing to a file is easy, and this question has been asked many times before. The best resource is the standard library documentation, and you can find such here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm

For the purpose of this question, I'll copy the salient example, which should be enough information to simply save a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * fp;

   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2012);

   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

You open the file, you write the contents, you close the file, and you're done.

Now the other part of your question, in regards to allocating enough memory for the log string.

I would first ask the question, do they want a string containing all the log files, or just the last log file? The solution is very different for each.

I will first say that this code:
    int logsize = sizeof(log_t) + 1;
is wrong. it's getting the size of the log_t struct, + 1, which is not correct. You want the size of the final string. This `log_t` struct is really the size of a `data_t` struct, plus a pointer to a `data_t`. The size of a `data_t` is the size of `time_t`, plus a char-pointer.

First ask yourself what a log entry will even look like. The data-structure is a string, the log message, plus a time_t entity. What is the length of time_t? It actually depends how you format it. What is the length of the string? Well you don't know, you need another function to tell you this.

The size of a single log message will be:
    strlen(logMessage) + strlen(format(time))

Where `format()` is a function which formats the time appropriately. You then need to recurse over all of the log entries, adding up each of their lengths. Be sure to add in memory for newlines between log-line entries, and then the final null-character.

This should be enough help to get you started.

Comment: For a _log file_, better to use `"r+"` than `"w+"` to avoid re-writing history.

Comment: It depends on the nature of their logging system. His logging system may read the file into memory and write the entire log out again when saving, in which case you'd want w. If his log is incremental then you'd want "a".
OP needs to understand his question and check which mode best suits his use-case.